# Android Sockets

Tags: android, sockets

I'm programming a simple Bluetooth chat.
When I want to handle sockets to receive and send message I don't know how to use these methods that i've implemented.

I attach my code and if some one know how to help me...

I have methods to create connection with thread, listen and write with socket. But I don't know how to use it on the main (onCreate).

Thank you.

```
public class messages_activity extends Activity {
private Button send;
private TextView message;
private EditText write;

private BluetoothSocket transferSocket;

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
final UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString("27012F0C-68AF-4FBF-8DBE-6BBAF7AA432A");


private boolean listening = false;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messages);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    write = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String macAddress = intent.getStringExtra("MacAddress"); //On macAddress I receive the macAddress of the other device that I want to send and receive

    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);

    startServerSocket(mBluetoothAdapter);
    connectToServerSocket(device, applicationUUID);



    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage(transferSocket, write.getText().toString()); //write is a textField when I write what I want to send
        }
    });



}

//Bluetooth Socket Server Connection

private UUID startServerSocket(BluetoothAdapter bluetooth){

    try{
        final BluetoothServerSocket btserver = bluetooth.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(mBluetoothAdapter.getName(), applicationUUID);

        Thread acceptThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    //Block until client connection established
                    BluetoothSocket serverSocket = btserver.accept();
                    //Start listening for messages
                    StringBuilder incoming = new StringBuilder();
                    listenForMessages(serverSocket, incoming);
                    //Add a reference to the socket used to send messages
                    transferSocket = serverSocket;
                }catch (IOException e){}
            }
        });

        acceptThread.start();

    }catch (IOException e){}

    return applicationUUID;
}



//Creating a Bluetooth client socket
private void connectToServerSocket (BluetoothDevice device, UUID uuid){
    try {
        BluetoothSocket clientSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);

        //Block until server connection accept
        clientSocket.connect();

        //Start listening for messages
        StringBuilder incoming = new StringBuilder();
        listenForMessages(clientSocket, incoming);


        //Add a reference to the socket used to send messages
        transferSocket = clientSocket;

        }catch (IOException e){}
}


private void sendMessage(BluetoothSocket socket, String message) {
    OutputStream outStream;
    try {
        outStream = socket.getOutputStream();

        // Add a stop character.
        byte[] byteArray = (message + " ").getBytes();
        byteArray[byteArray.length - 1] = 0;

        outStream.write(byteArray);
        outStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}



private void listenForMessages(BluetoothSocket socket, StringBuilder incoming){
    listening = true;
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    try{
        InputStream instream = socket.getInputStream();
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while(listening){
            bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
            if(bytesRead != -1){
                String result = "";
                while((bytesRead == bufferSize) && (buffer[bufferSize-1] != 0)){
                    result = result + new String (buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1 );
                    bytesRead = instream.read(buffer);
                }
                result = result + new String (buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1 );
                incoming.append(result);
                message.setText(incoming); //message is a textview to show what I've received

            }
            socket.close();
        }
    }catch(IOException e){}
    finally {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run the code so I don't know if it works.

listenForMessages shows the received message being inserted into the message textview   message.setText(incoming);

This should then show on your screen.

If you want a chat, you should be doing something like:

1. Enter text in send box, click send.
2. In the onClick method of send.onClickListener, add a line to the messagetext(Chat window) box showing your message being sent:
   ME: Hi! How are you?
3. Then clear the message text box
4. The onClick method then fires send message as coded.
5. When a message is received listenForMessage should add the received message to the Chat Window:  ID: message.
   FRIEND:  I'm all snowed in? You?

Now you are ready for another round of messages.

Comment: But the problem is about sockets. When the thread.accept() is runnable, I should have in transferSocket the socket that I can put in the other methods to send and listening sendings. startServerSocket(mBluetoothAdapter); //this create the socket to send and listen.                                                                                                               And now I should can put this socket in sendmessage(transferSocket);         But transferSocket is null. I've been debugging and I've seen it.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I would add code to validate every step you are taking to find out where it goes wrong.  Android.Bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.CheckBluetoothAddress to check that the mac address you are using is valid.

Comment: From code examples I have viewed, after you create the bluetooth adapter you have to enable it   BluetoothAdapter.enable.

Comment: I think the problem is on the transferSocket. When I start the thread, this create serverSocket on the run() method and then I save it on a variable transferSocket to be able to use it later in write() method. But when I debug I see transferSocket is "null". Then maybe my thread is not doing run() method.